# Create Intake List

Tags: project-server, pwa, project-online

I would like to create a list in PWA so that I can have users fill in the information that I need in order to create a new Project.   I don't see how to create a new list that is not attached to a project.  Any ideas?   This seems quite basic.   Is this documented somewhere?  I could not find on technet.

Comment: You mean creating a custom list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following instructions from the Project online.

- Go to the project online root site.
- Go to the site contents from the gear icon.
- You will find a '+ New' option to create a List/Library/App/Subsite.
- The 'List' option used to create a new list.

Make sure you have at least Edit rights on the site.

Let me know if I am out of your questions.

Comment: I think you are wrong

Comment: He wants to create a list to collect project details before project creation which is not related to projects.

Answer (score 4):

You have mentioned in your question

> I would like to create a list in PWA so that I can have users fill in
>   the information that I need **in order to create a new Project.**

So it's not just a direct custom list, you need + one trick that is "**Create Projects Option**" as I mentioned below,

- **At any site below** the PWA root site, Click on the Site Setting icon,
- Select `add a new APP`.
- Create a custom list with at least the mandatory fields of Project custom fields.
- Add a new item to your list, select your Item.
- From the above ribbon,  at Item tab, click on the `Create Projects`

[image]

- Map your list field with your project field **in order to create a new Project from list item**

For more details check my article at [Create a new Project based on SharePoint List Item in Project Server 2016](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/08/02/create-new-project-based-on-list-item-project-server-2016/)